# simplexml_load_file() issues within PHP class

Tags: php, simplexml

So I'm trying to use a class I found to fix an eCommerce problem I have.

[Original Blog Post](http://blog.smalldo.gs/2011/01/php-class-for-wa-states-destination-based-tax/)

In Washington State online stores need to determined a tax rate based on the shipping address.

[WA Sales Tax Rate Lookup URL Interface](http://dor.wa.gov/content/findtaxesandrates/retailsalestax/destinationbased/clientinterface.aspx)

**Class:**

```
/**
 * @author SmallDog
 * @contact dustin@smalldo.gs
 * @created 01-27-2011 
**/

class destinationTax
{
    private $dor_url = 'http://dor.wa.gov';

    function __construct(){ }

    function getTax($addr,$city,$zip)
    {
        $req = $this->dor_url."/AddressRates.aspx?output=xml&addr=$addr&city=$city&zip=$zip";
        return $this->_get_decoded($req);
    }

    private function _get_decoded($url)
    {
        $url = urlencode($url);
        if($xml = simplexml_load_file($url))
        {
            switch($xml->attributes()->code)
            {
                case 0:
                    // Code 0 means address was perfect
                    break;
                case 1:
                    $xml->msg = "Warning: The address was not found, but the ZIP+4 was located.";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $xml->msg = "Warning: Neither the address or ZIP+4 was found, but  the 5-digit ZIP was located.";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $xml->msg = "Error: The address, ZIP+4, and ZIP could not be found.";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    $xml->msg = "Error: Invalid arguements.";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    $xml->msg = "Error: Internal error.";
            }
        }
        else $xml = "Error: Could not load XML.";

        return  $xml;
    }
}
```

**Useage:**

```
$tax = new destinationTax;
$tax = $tax->getTax("123 Main Street", "Kirkland", "98033");
echo $tax->attributes()->rate;
```

**Error:**

> Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: URL
>   file-access is disabled in the server configuration in
>   /.../.../classes.php
>
> Warning:
>   simplexml_load_file(http://dor.wa.gov/AddressRates.aspx?output=xml&addr=123+Main+Street&city=Kirkland&zip=98033)
>   [function.simplexml-load-file]: failed to open stream: no suitable
>   wrapper could be found in /.../.../classes.php
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O
>   warning : failed to load external entity
>   "http%3A%2F%2Fdor.wa.gov%2FAddressRates.aspx%3Foutput%3Dxml%26addr%3D123+Main+Street%26city%3DKirkland%26zip%3D98033"
>   in  /.../.../classes.php
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object in
>    /.../.../tax.php

Comment: `URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration` is relatively unambiguous... See http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php for an explanation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your server does not support remote file access.  If you have cURL access, you could get the XML data that way, as exampled below:

```
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($curl);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

// ...
```